# Finding translation of the camera matrix

Tags: python, camera, computer-vision, translation, linear-algebra

Another question about computer vision.

A camera matrix (also known as projection matrix) maps a 3D point **X** (e.g. in the real world) to an image point **x** (in a photograph, for example) via the following relation:

```
l **x** = P **X**
```

P describes some external and internal characteristics of the camera (its orientation,  position and projection properties). When we refer to the projection properties, we use a calibration matrix K. Likewise, R represents the rotation of the camera and t its translation, so we can write P as:

```
P = K [ R | t ]
```

[ R | t ] means the concatenation of the matrix R and t.

```
R  is a matrix 3 X 3
t is a vector 3 X 1 
K is a matrix 3 X 3
[R | t ] is a matrix 3 X 4
As a consequence, P is a matrix 3 X 4
```

Well, enough introductions. I want to find the translation of the camera matrix P. According to the code in the book Computer Vision with Python, it can be found like this:

```
def rotation_matrix(a):
    """ Creates a 3D rotation matrix for rotation
    around the axis of the vector a. """
    a = array(a).astype('float')
    R = eye(4)
    R[:3,:3] = linalg.expm([[0,-a[2],a[1]],[a[2],0,-a[0]],[-a[1],a[0],0]])
    return R

tmp = rotation_matrix([0,0,1])[:3,:3]
Rt = hstack((tmp,array([[50],[40],[30]])))
P = dot(K, Rt)
K, R = linalg.rq(P[:,:3])

# This part gets rid of some ambiguity in the solutions of K and R
T = diag(sign(diag(K)))
if linalg.det(T) < 0:
    T[1,1] *= -1
    K = dot(K, T)
    R = dot(T, R) # T is its own inverse

t = dot(linalg.inv(K), P[:,3])
```

The code is self-contained. There we have `Rt` that is the matrix `[R | t]`. `P` is calculated as usual and an RQ factorization is performed. However, I don't understand that part. Why are we taking only the first 3 columns? Then we obtain the translation vector as the dot product of `K^{-1}` and the first 3 columns of P. Why? I haven't found a justification but maybe it's something obvious I'm missing.

By the way, the code seems to be a bit off. When I run it, I get a translation vector `[ 50. -40.  30.]` instead of `array([[50],[40],[30]])` that we used as input. We should get exactly the same. I don't know if this is due to the rotation matrix. I would also appreciate any help on that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You calculate the translation vector as the multiplication of `inv(K)` and **the 4th column of `P`**. Notice that in your code it says

```
t = dot(linalg.inv(K), P[:,3])
```

Where `P[:,3]` is the fourth column of the projection matrix since the indexing starts at 0. This means that getting back `t` is expected since `P = [KR | Kt]` so `Kt` is the 4th column. `inv(K) * Kt = t`

You can RQ decompose `P[:,:3]` into the calibration matrix `K` and the rotation matrix `R` again because `P = [KR | Kt]` and because calibration matrices are upper triangular and rotation matrices are orthogonal.

As to why you are getting a different translation vector than what you expected, I think it might be due to the fact that [QR decompositions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_decomposition) are not unique in general. As per wikipedia, they are only unique when we require that all the diagonal elements of `R` are positive. Here `R` is the upper triangular matrix, in your case `K`.

If your matrix `K` has a negative element anywhere on the diagonal you may get back a different `K` (perhaps only different in one sign) from the QR decomposition. This would mean that you don't get back the `t` you expected.

Comment: Excellent answer. Right! I got confused about P[:,3]. I didn't know you could do K[R|t] = [KR | Kt ]. Any comments on that? Regarding the different vectors I get, absolutely but I thought that issue was solved using T instead. I did a test and it worked correctly.

Comment: Well K[R|t] = [KR | Kt] comes from the fact that when you multiply matrices A * B what you are doing is A * [b1 b2 .. bn] = [A*b1 .. A*bn]. You are transforming the column space of B using A. Or in other words, a column n of A*B is obtained by taking the dot products of every row of A with column n of B.